# Moving question: prayer when posting a mezuzah

Tags: mezuzah, blessing

What prayer do you recite when posting a mezuzah?

Answer (score 6):

Believe it or not, the bracha for mezuza is right there in the [relevant Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mezuzah#Affixing_the_mezuzah):

> Blessed are You, Lord our God, King of the Universe, Who sanctified us with His mitzvot, and commanded us to affix a mezuzah.

I'm not copying in the Hebrew text, since I'm less willing to put God's name in Hebrew all over the place than I am to do so with the English word "God." You can find it in Hebrew there or in most [siddurim](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siddur).