# Mezzuzahs- putting them up, and saying brachot

Tags: halacha, blessing, mezuzah, issur-vheter

Is there an "issur" regarding not putting up a mezuzzah?  Is there such thing as having 30 days until the issue kicks in?  Also, can you say the [bracha](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/61/moving-question/62#62) each time you put one up?  Or, if two different people hang them up, can they each say the bracha?

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/67717/759

Answer (score 2):

I have information about everything but the theoretical "issur" question from *Oholei Yeshurun, Vol. 2*, Chapter 1: "Laws of Mezuzah", by R' Aaron Felder. Please note that while R' Felder is a talented and respected [Posek](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Posek) who cites an impressive collection of sources, his is by no means the last word on the subject. If these questions come up practically, you should consult your Rabbi.

- "Is there such thing as having 30 days until the issue kicks in?"

  Here are the relevant passages from Section 3: "Laws Concerning the Time For Affixing the Mezuzah":

  > 2) Immediately upon entering a purchased [as opposed to rented -IM] dwelling, the owner should affix a *Mezuzah* and recite the blessing.
  >   4) A teneant who rented a dwelling outside of *Eretz Yisroel* for less than thirty days, is not required to affix a *Mezuzah*.
  >   5) a) Upon entering a dwelling rented for thirty days or more, a blessing should be recited when affixing the *Mezuzah*.
  >   ... b) The *Mezuzah* may be affixed on the morning of the thirtieth day if one desires to wait until that time.
  >   ... c) If one wishes to affix the *Mezuzah* but delay recitation of the blessing until the thirtieth day, it should be touched before reciting the blessing. However, it is preferable to remove and reaffix the *Mezuzah* before reciting the blessing.
  >   ... d) The blessing should be said the day before the thirtieh day if it is a *Shabbos* or *Yom Tov*.
  >   7) Even if one left the dwelling for a period of time during the first thirty days, a *Mezuzah* is still required by the thirtieth day.

  Actually, the following might shed some light on your issur question:

  > 13) One may remain in a dwelling that has no *Mezuzah*.
- "Also, can you say the bracha each time you put one up?"

  I'm not sure what case you're referring to. Do you mean each time you take down and put up the same one, or for each mezuzah in a houseful thereof?

  If it's the former, it depends on the circumstances of the mezuzah's removal and replacement. There are a bunch of different cases discussed in Section 10: "Requirement of a Blessing Upon Affixing the Mezuzah" and Section 11: "Laws Pertaining to Conditions When a Blessing is Not Recited." If you amend your question to refer to a specific case, I'll quote the relevant ruling from these sections.

  If it's the latter, here's the relevant material from Section 12 "Laws Concerning the Recitation of the Blessing":

  > 4) a) When *Mezuzus* are being placed on several doorposts, one recites the blessing only once. This law applies only if one intended that the blessing be for all subsequent *Mezuzos*.
  >   ... b) The text of the blessing for many *Mezuzos* is the same as for affixing a single *Mezuzah*.
  >   5) One should not converse from the time the blessing is recited until all the *Mezuzos* are affixed. If one did speak about a subject other than the mounting of the *Mezuzos*, the blessing must be recited prior to the placement of the remaining *Mezuzos*.
- "Or, if two different people hang them up, can they each say the bracha?"

  From the same section:

  > 8) One who could not complete putting up all the *Mezuzos*, may appoint another person to complete the task. This person need not have been present when the blessing was recited. [Apparently, the second person does not recite a blessing in this case. -IM]
  >   9) a) One individual may recite the blessing for several people in the same building. The one reciting the blessing should have the intention of including them, and those listening should have the intention of being included in the recitation.
  >   ... b) Those listening, should answer *Boruch Hu U'voruch Shmo* [I don't understand this ruling. -IM]. If *Amen* was not said, the blessing is not repeated.

Comment: Isaac, yes, the Boruch Hu U'voruch Shmo thing is confusing.  It probably has something to do with the practice of NOT saying "Boruch Hu U'voruch Shmo" when listening to another's bracha if you're having your obligation fulfilled by them.

Comment: Right, so I don't understand why this case is different if the second party is, in fact, using the same blessing. Perhaps someone can ask R' Felder when they see him. We have users who do.

Comment: I think the circumstances under which the second person is hanging them should be clarified.   If it's 2-3 people sharing an apartment??    In a situation where they all share the responsibility for the performance of the performance of the Mitzvah equally then we might not let the Bracha of the first person be carried over to the others as they are not acting as a Shaliach for the first, but acting in their own right.  While it seems that the have "rishut" to be included in someone else saying the Bracha, it would also seem that they can exclude themselves and recite their own.

Comment: I think it's a typo and should read "should not answer Boruch Hu U'voruch Shmo".

Comment: Why no mention of renting a dwelling for more than 30 days in Israel?

Comment: @DoubleAA I read somewhere that the 30-day period outside Israel was because at a time Jews could be expelled of their dwellings for 30 days. Therefore it was only after 30 days it would become __their__ dwelling and deserve a mezuza. This would explain why things are different in Israel where presumable they were less likely to be expelled. I don't have a source but am interested in other explanations for the 30 days. An important implication would be that, now that rental agreements are secure, there is no 30-day period anymore

Comment: @MichaelBloch The traditional explanation I believe is that it is due to Yishuv Eretz Yisrael that the rule is shorter there. I always understood this to mean that when a Jew dwells in Israel there is a fundamentally higher lever of Keviut to his dwelling. Sorta like how Tevel is Nikba' for Maaser on Shabbat. (Rashi Menachot 44a gives a more technical explanation about how in Israel you are more likely to re-rent to a Jew so Chazal ordered you to put a Mezuza up soon so the apartment will look more enticing to future renters who you have to leave it up for.)

Comment: @DoubleAA I formulated this as a question with sources here https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/66555/does-one-really-have-30-days-to-put-up-a-mezuza-outside-eretz-israel

Answer (score 0):

I'll try and look this up for real and edit later...  But here's what I can add from my recollection

1) You should try to mount main entrance mezuzot as soon as possible
2) There is a 30 grace period, I believe this relates to it becoming your established dwelling and not a temporary residence like a sukkah that is patur (exempt) from mezuzah
3) While not mounting a mezuza is nullifying a positive commandment I don't know of there is an "issur". 
4) If you are putting more than one up at the same time, you may only make one Bracha. If you're putting them up with a substantial break in between then you would make another Bracha.   One should not seek to do this since it is forbidden to make a "Bracha She'aino Tzricha" a Bracha that is not necessary. 
5) It seems to me that if two different people are mounting them they can each make their own Bracha

Comment: There is no such thing as a thirty day grace period for a mezuzah. Unfortunately, this is a common misconception. If you purchase a dwelling anywhere or if you rent a house in Eretz Yisrael the obligation to affix a mezuzah is immediate. The thirty day rule applies only to renting a house outside of Eretz Yisrael, and not because there is a 'grace period', but because there is no obligation to affix a mezuzah to a rented dwelling outside Eretz Yisrael until thirty days have passed.