# When do you place the Mezuzah?

Tags: halacha, mezuzah

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Mezzuzahs- putting them up, and saying brachot…](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/121/mezzuzahs-putting-them-up-and-saying-brachot)

When do you place the Mezuzah? 30 days after beginning rental or moving in?

Comment: I have a different question is it 39 days from moving in or thirty days from the begining of the payment of rent ?

Comment: I read somewhere that the 30-day period outside Israel was because at a time Jews could be expelled of their dwellings for 30 days. Therefore it was only after 30 days it would become __their__ dwelling and deserve a mezuza. This would explain why things are different in Israel where presumable they were less likely to be expelled. I don't have a source but am interested in other explanations for the 30 days. An important implication would be that, now that rental agreements are secure, there is no 30-day period anymore

Comment: re my last comment I researched this further and formulated this as a question with sources here https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/66555/does-one-really-have-30-days-to-put-up-a-mezuza-outside-eretz-israel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the section from *Oholei Yeshurun* that I quoted in [this answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/121/mezzuzahs-putting-them-up-and-saying-brachot/132#132). The language used there for when to start the clock is "upon entering." I expect that that refers to moving in, not to any off-site formal transaction.