# Re Mezuzah: What is the definition of a Pundak and when does it apply?

Tags: halacha, eretz-yisrael, mezuzah

We learn in Shulchan Aruch, Yoreh Deah 286:22 -  [סימן רפו - מקומות החיבים במזוזה](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01976_part_41.html#HtmpReportNum0001_L2) - that if you rent a house in Eretz Yisrael you have to affix a Mezuza immediately.

However, if you live in a פֻנְדָּק (*pundak*) you are exempt from affixing a Mezuza for the first 30 days.

> **כב** הַשּׂוֹכֵר בַּיִת בְּחוּצָה לָאָרֶץ **וְהַדָּר בְּפֻנְדָּק בְּאֶרֶץ יִשְׂרָאֵל**, פָּטוּר מִמְּזוּזָה שְׁלֹשִׁים יוֹם. **וְהַשּׂוֹכֵר בַּיִת בְּאֶרֶץ יִשְׂרָאֵל**, חַיָּב בִּמְזוּזָה מִיָּד, מִשּׁוּם יִשּׁוּב אֶרֶץ יִשְׂרָאֵל.‏
>   
>    <sup>וְהוּא הַדִּין לְשׁוֹאֵל בַּיִת דִּינוֹ כְּשׂוֹכֵר (בֵּית יוֹסֵף בְּשֵׁם הר''ר מָנוֹחַ וכ''מ בְּשַׁ''ס) .</sup>‏

**What is the definition of a פֻנְדָּק and when does it apply?**

My guess:

A פֻנְדָּק seems to be like a motel where you rent a bed on a nightly basis.

Test cases:

Seems clear cut:

- Renting a **furnished home** - clearly *renting* and not a פֻנְדָּק, as you want the entire home, not just the beds.
- **Youth Hostel**: Seems to be a פֻנְדָּק since all you get is the bed.

Not so clear:

- **Hotels**: Could be a פֻנְדָּק since all you care about is the beds; you wouldn't complain if they upgraded you after a few days.
- **[Zimmer](http://www.balashon.com/2006/06/tzimmer.html)**: Could be a פֻנְדָּק like a hotel, on the other hand, you'd be upset if they made you move across the village every few days, even to a better zimmer.

Any sources or educated guesses would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The source for this halacha is a gemara in [Menachot 44a](https://www.sefaria.org/Menachot.44a.13?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en). There Koren translates *pundak* as a **guesthouse** while artscroll translates it as an **inn**.

For more on this topic see [Does one really have 30 days to put up a mezuza outside Eretz Israel?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/66555/11501) and the sources linked there.

Comment: רש"י על מנחות מ״ד א:יג:א: פונדק - שֶלָנים בו עוִִברים ושבים:

Comment: ערוך השולחן, יורה דעה רפ״ו:מ״ח: 
אמרו חכמינו ז"ל במנחות (מנחות מד א): הדר בפונדק – פטור ממזוזה, דדירת עראי היא לפני האורח, שאינו עומד שם רק איזה ימים. אך אם יושב שם שלושים יום – חייב במזוזה, דהוי כקבע. ונראה לי דזהו כשבעל הפונדק הוא עובד כוכבים