# Mezuzah on a store door?

Tags: halacha, mezuzah, business, responsa, ownership

If a Jewish person owned a store as a small business, do they have to put a mezuzah on their store doors? Or would this not be considered a “dwelling place” which requires a mezuzah?

This is all of course if they own the store for more than 30 days in which they would be obligated in mezuzah. Sources for the Halacha or responsa very much appreciated.

Comment: 30 days is only relevant to home rentals outside israel. Other cases are obligated in mezuza immediately.

Comment: https://ohr.edu/8068

Comment: Thanks, but I’m talking outside of a store’s doors, not an internal office building where one spends their time @shmuel

Comment: @DoubleAA, a friend of mine, who has beki'ut in Chovat haDor actually says that the 30 days aren't relevant outside of Israel for a lease. He's also a sofer, so I trust his understanding of the halachah

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt I'm not a sofer and I don't have beki'ut yet (despite working on it :->) but I agree with your friend, see [Does one really have 30 days to put up a mezuza outside Eretz Israel?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/66555/11501)

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt Depends how long your lease is...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The practice is to put up a mezuza without a blessing. The simple summary (from [aish](https://aish.com/mezuzah-in-office/)) is

> Some of the earlier authorities did not consider an office a true
> place of residence since we do not truly live there. Later
> authorities, however, disagree since people typically do eat and
> sometimes nap or sleep in their offices. **As a result, today the
> practice is to put a mezuzah up in an office, but without a blessing.**

[dinonline](https://dinonline.org/2023/08/18/mezuzah-part-iii/) brings the halachic reasoning

> The Shulchan Aruch (YD 286:11) rules that a store in the marketplace
> does not require a mezuzah. The Levush (YD 286:11) and Shach (ibid 21)
> explain this is because a store is a temporary dwelling, and the Torah
> requires a mezuzah only on permanent residences. The Shulchan Aruch
> compares a store to a succah on Succos and a ship’s cabin in their
> (non)-mezuzah obligation.
>
> This halacha puzzles contemporary poskim since we are required to
> affix a mezuzah on storage room doorposts, and if comparing their
> doorpost’s volume of traffic, stores rate much higher. Besides, a
> store is also used to “store” merchandise both when open, and closed.
> Why, therefore, should a store require a mezuzah less than a storage
> space?
>
> - The Taz maintains (YD 286:10) that a store is only used during the day and not at night, and in order for a space to be considered
>   inhabited it has to be used for its designated purpose both day and
>   night. Although it also serves to store merchandise, the space is not
>   intended for storage. Rather, its main purpose is commercial, and
>   storage is only a secondary use.
> - The Yad Haketana (Mezuzah 2:21, quoted in Pischei Teshuva footnote 10) disagrees with the Taz’s explanation. In his opinion, the Shulchan
>   Aruch refers here to a storefront from which merchandise is removed
>   every night, or a stall in the marketplace that is used only on market
>   days. This is the kind of store for which a mezuza not required, but
>   other stores do require a mezuzah. (This opinion is also mentioned in
>   the Ben Ish Chai [Rav Pe’alim II YD 36:3). [...]
> - Rav Moshe Feinstein (Igros Moshe YD I, 178) rules that if a business is not active every day it is certainly exempted from
>   mezuzah. Apparently, he follows the Taz’s opinion that exempts every
>   store and business from affixing a mezuzah despite serving as a
>   storage for merchandise or business tools. He does, nevertheless, take
>   in account the Yad Haketana’s opinion, and therefore requires a
>   mezuzah affixed on a business doorpost, albeit without a bracha.
> - Rav Elyashiv, though (Shvus Yitzchak chapter 2:2) requires a  mezuzah affixed on a store with a bracha.
>
> **Many poskim rule differently in this matter, depending upon various factors such as if there is a coffee room or not, and how a business
> is used. Every case requires individual consideration and ruling, and
> one business cannot be compared to another.**

For further halachic references see also [here](https://shulchanaruchharav.com/halacha/mezuzah-on-store-or-office-is-a-storefront-or-office-obligated-to-have-a-mezuzah-and-is-a-blessing-to-be-recited/).

Comment: Thanks very much