# At what stage of moving into a home should there be a mezuza?

Tags: mezuzah

There have been a number of questions relating to putting up a mezuza when moving into a rented home (or any home whose permanence is in question).  When moving into a purchased home, at what stage must the mezuza be put up?  Before moving in belongings? Before sleeping there the first time?  Within a specific number of days?

For reference, these are the related questions:

[When do you place the Mezuzah?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/680/when-do-you-place-the-mezuzah)

[If you put up a mezuzah before 30 days, can you make a blessing?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/67717/if-you-put-up-a-mezuzah-before-30-days-can-you-make-a-blessing)

[Mezzuzahs- putting them up, and saying brachot](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/121/mezzuzahs-putting-them-up-and-saying-brachot)

Comment: This seems to ask a question asked in the last question you link to. Why isn't it a duplicate?

Comment: The first answer to the last question you link to says, "**Immediately upon entering a purchased [as opposed to rented -IM] dwelling, the owner should affix a Mezuzah and recite the blessing.**" I think it's a duplicate.

Comment: I should have clarified... What is meant by "**immediately** upon entering a purchased dwelling"? When I buy it? When I start moving things in? When I change my address in my ID? When I actually sleep there?

Comment: The way I understand immediatly upon entering, and the way I have seen everyone do it, is that the day you move in you put up the mezuza. Whether you can wait until sleeping there or not is a matter of preference and something to discuss with your local rabbi. Since there is an idea of not passing over a mitzva, and this is a mitzva d'oraita, I see no reason to wait

Comment: The only reason to wait is that I want to move the mezuzot from my current house to the new one, and I don't want to remove the mezuzot before I've actually moved.